# can't get values in foreach from Viewbag mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to get values from userList viewbag.i can't figure out the solution. Error is:

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'name'

though in ViewBag.userList contains data (2 objects) which i can see while debugging

```
@foreach (var aUser in ViewBag.userList)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@aUser.name</td>
        <td>@aUser.username</td>
        .....
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UserEdit","Users")</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "UserDelete", "Users")</td>
    </tr>
}
```

I have a superclass and a childclass

superclass

```
public partial class user
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    ...
    public string user_role { get; set; }
}
```

childclass

```
public class UserSub: user
{
    public string CreatedUserName { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedUserName { get; set; }
    
}
```

In my controller i used linq to get values from database and stored it to Viewbag.userList. My controller function is

```
public ActionResult UserList()
{
    IEnumerable<user> users = null;
    users = dbEntities.users.ToList();
    
    if (users != null)
    {
        var userLists = (from a in users join b in users on a.created_user_id equals b.id select new { a.name, a.username, a.password, a.user_role, a.is_enable, a.is_approved, CreatedUserName = b.name, a.create_time, a.is_android, a.device_id }).ToList();
        ViewBag.userList = userLists;  
    }
    return View();
}
```

tried `List<UserSub> users=ViewBag.userList`....getting error too

Comment: Because `ViewBag.userList` is a collection of an anonymous object. You need to project your data into a model (containing properties `name`, `username`, `password` etc). And do not use `ViewBag` - pass the model to the view)

Comment: tried casting...but there are error too

Comment: Why can't you try pass it as a Model `return View(userLists);` instead of in a ViewBag

Comment: Cast to what? You need `yourQuery.Select(x => new someModel{ .... }`

Comment: userLists = (from a in users join b in users on a.created_user_id equals b.id select(c=> new UserSub {name = a.name, username = a.username, password = a.password,user_role = a.user_role,is_enable = a.is_enable,is_approved = a.is_approved,create_time = a.create_time, is_android = a.is_android, device_id = a.device_id,CreatedUserName = b.name}) ).ToList();

Comment: error: The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **ViewModel** to share data between view and controller.

For example, first create the **ViewModel**:

```
public class userViewModel{       
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string username { get; set; }
   public string user_role { get; set; }
   public string CreatedUserName { get; set; }
   public string ModifiedUserName { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

You can put all data that you need in your view model... Then, I'll recommend you create a class in your model with all the queries that you need (you have to investigate how to do), but you can get the queries from your controller (if you want).

Well, edit your **controller** function:

```
public ActionResult UserList()
{
    List<userViewModel> userVM = new List<userViewModel>(); //Important! Don't return all the query, just the data that you need.
    IEnumerable<user> users = null;
    users = dbEntities.users.ToList();

    if (users != null)
    {
        var userLists = (from a in users join b in users on a.created_user_id equals b.id select new { a.name, a.username, a.password, a.user_role, a.is_enable, a.is_approved, CreatedUserName = b.name, a.create_time, a.is_android, a.device_id }).ToList(); //I'm going to suppose that your query is ok and you get all the data that you need...

        foreach (var item in userLists)
        {
             userVM.Add(new userVM(){
                userVM.name = item.name;
                userVM.username = item.username;
                userVM.user_role = item.user_role;
                .......
             });                 
        }            
    }
    return View(userVM); //return your view model
}
```

Finally, modify your **view** and call the **ViewModel** `userViewModel`

```
@model Model.ViewModel.userViewModel //It depends on the namespace
//Then try something likes this...
@foreach (var aUser in Model) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>@aUser.name</td>            
        <td>@aUser.username</td>
        .....
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UserEdit","Users")</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "UserDelete", "Users")</td>
    </tr>
}
```

That's the idea, improve my answer. ;)

Comment: Just a small comment - you probably don't want to call `ToList()` on your `dbEntities.users` before you put a predicate (where clause) against them - otherwise you are selecting everything from the DB and filtering in .NET rather than doing the filter using the DB engine (assuming that applies)